# apply max to each column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, max

I would like to replace all columns values with the max value of their respective columns.
For example from this dataframe :

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6], 'C':[9,2,3]})
   A  B  C
0  1  4  9
1  2  5  2
2  3  6  3
```

I would like to get :

```
   A  B  C
0  3  6  9
1  3  6  9
2  3  6  9
```

There should be a simple pandas way with apply but I can't find it...

Comment: Why do people keep trying to use apply for everything?

Comment: This seems like somewhat of an odd thing to do; why would you need such a repetitive DataFrame?

Answer (score 2):

Check `assign`

```
df0.assign(**df0.max())
Out[22]: 
   A  B  C
0  3  6  9
1  3  6  9
2  3  6  9
```

Comment: it looks like the first one doesn't work when number of columns of df0 is different of number of rows

Answer (score 1):

You could use numpy's [`max`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html) and [`broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html):

```
import numpy as np

pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(df0.values.max(0), df0.shape), columns=df0.columns)

   A  B  C
0  3  6  9
1  3  6  9
2  3  6  9
```

---

Timings -

```
df = pd.concat([df0]*10_000, axis=0)

%timeit df.assign(**df.max())
# 2.71 ms ± 194 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.max()*pd.DataFrame(1, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
# 6.19 ms ± 951 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(df.values.max(0), df.shape), columns=df.columns)
# 310 µs ± 21.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution.

```
for column in df0:
    df0[column] = df0[column].max()


   A  B  C
0  3  6  9
1  3  6  9
2  3  6  9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df.max()*pd.DataFrame(1, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C
0   3   6   9
1   3   6   9
2   3   6   9
```